# OpenRasta Framework for building httpServices

Tags: httpservice, openrasta

Is any one aware of any websites which has some practical examples of using OpenRasta to build Http services

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you can convert from vb.net to c#, I have a very small sample available on bitbucket that gets you of the ground: https://bitbucket.org/starlogicsh/openrasta-vbsample